# Common practice for partially masking/hiding a variable in django templates?

Tags: python, django

So basically, `example@gmail.com` should be appeared as `ex****le@gmail.com` in the page, and I use `{{ email }}` in the template for that email.

What's the common practice for doing this? And is there a way to do this directly in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/) something like: `{{ email | hide_some }}` and you would change the string middle chars to stars.